# Getting System.InvalidOperationException when Trying to foreach loop over a List?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

I have the following code. I've been trying to debug the error stated in the title for 4 hours now, but unfortunately I understand nothing at this point. I come from Python, so sorry if this stuff is elementary. Also, the code is not the best - in my attempts to debug it, it probably became unorganised and unnecessary at points.

Code context: this program is created to emulate the creation of a Galaxy Gate (portal, if you like) in a video game, to try and recreate the cost - see how much it will cost you without you having to check using actual game currency.

Note that this error consistently happens at the second execution of the for-each loop (when there are no more values left in the list being iterated over - I guess: I may be wrong).

Screenshot of error: http://prntscr.com/dep0xv

This is the place where I am getting the error, at the for each loop:

```
List<int> partsBuiltTwo = new List<int>();
partsBuiltTwo = ggPart(gateEnd, multiplier, partsBuilt);

if (!(partsBuiltTwo.Count == 0))
{
    foreach (int part in partsBuiltTwo) //error
    {
         partsBuilt.Add(part);
         label28.Text = (partsBuilt.Count).ToString();
    }
}
```

This is the function ggPart being called:

```
private List<int> ggPart(int gateEnd, int multiplier, List<int> partsBuilt)
    {
        int generatedPart = random.Next(1, gateEnd); //Generate part

        if (multiplier > 1) //If we have a multiplier, use it on gate part
        {
            if (partsBuilt.Contains(generatedPart)) //If we hit a multiplier with a multiplier, give multiplier parts
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < multiplier; i++) //Give us as many parts as multipliers
                {
                    if (partsBuilt.Count < gateEnd)
                    {
                        while (partsBuilt.Contains(generatedPart))
                        {
                            generatedPart = random.Next(1, gateEnd);
                        }
                        partsBuilt.Add(generatedPart);
                        updateReceivedValues(5, multiplier);
                        label26.Text = "x" + multiplier.ToString();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        continue;
                    }
                }
            }
            else //If we hit a multiplier on a normal part, give us multiplier + 1 parts
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < multiplier + 1; i++) //Give us as many parts as multipliers
                {
                    if (partsBuilt.Count < gateEnd)
                    {
                        while (partsBuilt.Contains(generatedPart))
                        {
                            generatedPart = random.Next(1, gateEnd);
                        }
                        partsBuilt.Add(generatedPart);
                        updateReceivedValues(5, multiplier);
                        label26.Text = "x" + multiplier.ToString();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        continue;
                    }
                }
            }
            multiplier = 1;
            label26.Text = "x" + multiplier.ToString();
        }
        else //If we don't have a multiplier and get a gate parts
        {
            if (partsBuilt.Contains(generatedPart)) //If we get a part we already have
            {
                multiplier += 1; //Increase multiplier by 1
            }
            else //If we get a part we don't already have
            {
                partsBuilt.Add(generatedPart); //Add part
                updateReceivedValues(5, multiplier);
                label26.Text = "x" + multiplier.ToString();
            }
        }

        //int[] newArray = partsBuilt; 

        return partsBuilt;
        //built += 1;
    }
```

Why am I getting this error, and how do I fix it? Please be as descriptive as possible or provide me with a way to debug this, as I cannot continue the program I have spent a whole day on unless I fix this error.

Also, any tips are appreciated.

Comment: @MDXF Oh yeah I should have thought about fixing that part...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are sending `partsBuilt` to `ggPart` method as parameter and inside the method updating same and return same. at the end you are assigning the returned value to `partsBuiltTwo`. Finally both your  `partsBuilt` and `partsBuiltTwo` are same. 
in the next loop you are iterating over `partsBuiltTwo` and adding to `partsBuilt` that is same as iterate and update same which is not allowed with `foreach` loop

```
if (!(partsBuiltTwo.Count == 0))
{
    foreach (int part in partsBuiltTwo) 
    {
         //partsBuiltTwo and partsBuilt are same you don't need to add items again back to partsBuilt
         //partsBuilt.Add(part);
         label28.Text = (partsBuilt.Count).ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This makes sense so I got rid of partsBuiltTwo. (it was for debugging). The foreach loop wasn't needed after all.